# Type error when using imap, mailparser library in typescript

Tags: typescript, imap

```
imap.connect();

    imap.once("ready", () => {
      imap.openBox("INBOX", false, async () => {
        imap.search(
          [
            "UNSEEN",
            ["SINCE", new Date()],
          ],
          (err, results) => {
            const f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: "" });
            f.on("message", async (msg) => {
              msg.on("body", (stream, info) => {
                simpleParser(stream, (error, parsed) => { // Here!
                }
              }
            }
           // ...
```

In the above code,
simpleParser(stream, (error, parsed) => { }
says stream is not of the correct type.
Below is the error message displayed in stream. Can you tell me why?

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(source: Source, callback: (err: any, mail: ParsedMail) => void): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Source'.
      Property 'compose' is missing in type 'ReadableStream' but required in type 'Stream'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(source: Source, options?: MailParserOptions | undefined): Promise<ParsedMail>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReadableStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Source'.ts(2769)
```

In other projects, the error message is not output even in the same code.

Comment: What do you mean by other projects? Are you using it somewhere else as well without any error? If so, check the version of the library there to match it.